# How can you filter on "Keys" using jq?

Tags: jq

I am looking to filter a JSON stream based on its keys. Here is the public JSON file:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/okta-ip-ranges/ip_ranges.json that I am trying to wrangle. When I filter this for keys `jq 'keys'`, I get the following output

```
[
  "apac_cell_1",
  "emea_cell_1",
  "emea_cell_2",
  "preview_cell_1",
  "preview_cell_2",
  "preview_cell_3",
  "us_cell_1",
  "us_cell_10",
  "us_cell_11",
  "us_cell_12",
  "us_cell_2",
  "us_cell_3",
  "us_cell_4",
  "us_cell_5",
  "us_cell_6",
  "us_cell_7"
]
```

I am trying to get all the `ip_ranges` associated with the keys starting with "us_cell_*" and I have not found a way to do it. Most of the filtering seems to be focused on the values and not the keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
to_entries | map(select(.key | startswith("us_cell_")) | .value.ip_ranges) | add
```

[Try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/GT8P5IF8tS).

[`to_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) maps the root object into an array of objects with `key` and `value` fields corresponding to the fields of the original object.

We filter that to retain only those which have a key starting with "us_cell_", map it further to keep only the ip ranges and finally merge those arrays together.

Comment: That works. Thank you so much. I will dig into the map function more.